# Регулярное выражение для разного написания одного слова

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть слово, **"решил:"** в документе. И в разных документах он может писаться по разному и вот некоторый список:

- решил:
- р е ш и л:
- р е ш и л :
- р  е  ш  и  л:
- р е ши л:
- р еши л:

И много разных таких вариаций. Можно ли написать какую то регулярку под это слово.
И если не сложно, такую же регулярку, под слово **"постановил:"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так можно

```
р\s*е\s*ш\s*и\s*л\s*:
```

если же между буками возможен лишь 1 пробел максимум:

```
р\s?е\s?ш\s?и\s?л\s?:
```

думаю под слово "постановил" вы сможете сделать сами

проверить работу регулярок удобно на сайте https://regex101.com/